# How to compute the CI of an Inverse Gaussian distribution?

Tags: distributions, confidence-interval

I have come across some formula for calculating the confidence interval (CI) of data from an Inverse Gaussian distribution. But, being really new in stats, I am unable to figure out what to do.

On page 51 of [this](http://www.idescat.cat/sort/sort321/32.1.2.arefi-etal.pdf) document, there is a formula. But I am not sure how to compute the different elements of the formula. Can anyone kindly help me out ?

(In the picture below, while I know that $\hat{\mu}$ means the mean and $n$ means the number of observation. I am not sure what to make of $k$ or $\lambda$... .)

[image]

Comment: Why do you want to implement these?  It appears the principal conclusion of the paper is that the likelihood ratio interval (Definition 3) is preferable to these two.  That definition contains a formula for the interval (without involving $z_{1-\alpha/2}$) and explains how to estimate $\lambda$.  I also see you originally tagged this question with "Normal-distribution."  Are you aware that the Inverse Gaussian is *not* normal?  It has [only tenuous and circumstantial relationships](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_Gaussian_distribution) to normal (Gaussian) distributions.

Comment: about the tag: if i write gaussian, it changes to normal. my apologies.

Comment: Also, I am not trying to implement anything, just need to know how to compute the CI of an inverse gaussian distribution.

Comment: Then you want to focus on Definition 3, Ahsan, not on the first two!  ("Compute" == "implement", BTW.)  The reason why "Gaussian" is synonymous with "Normal" is that the probability density function (PDF) of a Normal distribution is Gaussian: they are one and the same thing, but differ distinctly from the Inverse Gaussian.  I wanted to make sure you weren't just looking for a Normal (Gaussian) CI, which is easier to compute.

Comment: right, for a normal CI, i can directly use `CI var` in Stata ..for a inv. gaussian, I cant do that...

Comment: i am happy on any formula that calculates the CI...i just focused on the 3rd one...

Comment: Actually, if you have enough data, the Normal-theory CI will do just fine.  For example, take the dataset of 23 numbers in that paper and compute their (Normal) CI: it is $[56.01,88.43]$, not far from the three CIs studied in the paper.  "Enough" is relative: when the data are not highly skewed, just a few values will work, but when they are very highly skewed, you might need hundreds or thousands before the Normal CI is acceptable.

Comment: I have two thousand data point....and in the histogram they look like inv. gaussian. do you think it will be ok to use Normal CI ? I mean, the value is not very highly critical to my work as long as it stays lower than some other value.

Comment: It depends on the skewness, but the data would have to be *extremely* skewed for a normal CI to be inaccurate.  Just be aware that a Normal UCL is nevertheless likely to be *slightly* less than the Inverse Gaussian CI, so if the UCL is very close to your critical threshold, you will want to be careful (and might consider using the Inverse Gaussian CI).

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/2061/discussion-between-ahsan-and-whuber)